# Cannot click on Upload button due to new browser window that opens at run time only

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to click on the Upload button but when the script runs this click event triggers a new browser to open which I cannot simulate when I try to test it manually.

I deliberately click on Start link (in the code) hoping that this new window opens only the first time and can be handled then and there, and thereafter I can concentrate on the click event of the Upload button in the parent window. But once again it brings up the new browser window.

How should I handle this?

```
driver.get("http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/a[1]/b")).click(); //Start link  
Thread.sleep(4000); 

 Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();       
 String firstWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
 handles.remove(firstWindowHandle);
 String winHandle = handles.iterator().next();

    if (winHandle != firstWindowHandle) {
        String secondWindowHandle = winHandle;
        driver.switchTo().window(secondWindowHandle);
        driver.close();
        driver.switchTo().window(firstWindowHandle);

    }       
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class=pole_plik]")).sendKeys(path);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt=Upload]")).click(); //upload button
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code, It works Tested it.

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php");
driver.manage().window().maximize();


driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class=pole_plik]")).sendKeys("/Users/jeevanbhushetty/Desktop/dock.jpg");

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("check_recipient('s000.tinyupload.com');");
```

Comment: It does. Thanks! How did you arrive at this method?

Comment: Your welcome, `check_recipient()` function is written in your HTML markup, which gets executed on click of upload button.

Comment: So... because check_recipient() is inside a script tag you decided to use JavascriptExecutor? I need a bit more help to understand this concept.

Comment: Being frank, code written in '<script>' tag `function check_recipient(file_server_domain) {
            postIt(file_server_domain);
        }` is of no use it is just calling another function in other script, you can directly call the function itself. In your script if you replace `check_recipient('s000.tinyupload.com');` with `postIt('s000.tinyupload.com');` script will still work. Just one additional call is made which is of no use. Coming back to your question, using `JavascriptExecutor` class  of selenium you can execute any javascript.

Comment: why doesn't executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element); work?